# Работа layuots (работа с с виджетом dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset,)

Tags: yii2

подключил себе виджет админки AdminLTE вот [отсюда](https://github.com/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset)  возник вопрос поскольку все страницы  подключаются как layouts , каким образом можно передавать данные с моделей в layouts и можно ли создать и как подключить контролер который будет осуществлять передачу данных из базы данных в layouts